# В чем тут ошибка свойство inner html

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  if(document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length > 0){
    for(var i = document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      document.querySelectorAll('._Table')[i].remove(); 
    };
  };
  
  table.classList.add('_Table');
  
  tableData.forEach(function(rowData,i) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData,j) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.id=i+'_'+j
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col1").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col2").value;
  var row_mas = [];
  var col_mas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var col_mas = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      col_mas.push(0);
    }
    row_mas.push(col_mas);
  }
  createTable(row_mas);
});

document.querySelector(".btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
   var row = document.querySelector(".col3").value;
   var col = document.querySelector(".col4").value;
   var gell = document.getElementById(row+"_"+col);
   gell.innerHTML="1"
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
th,td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
  <input type="text" class="col2">
   <button class="btn">Go</button>
   <br/>
   <input type="text" class="col3">
   <input type="text" class="col4">
   <button class="btn2">koordinats</button>
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей

Comment: В этом сниппете всё работает, с ручной инициализацией и с ручной же проверкой границ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка очевидна:

> Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Это значит, что результат вызова `document.getElementById(row+"_"+col)` -> `null`

Comment: а почему между row+ +col стоит нижнее подчеркивание "_" ?

Comment: @Anton, это же твой код? :-) ты не помнишь почему писал `_`? Здесь просто собирается строка, которая должна совпадать с id элемента, который надо найти, например: `1_1` или `2_2` и подчеркивание просто разделяется части, чтобы визуально по разметке можно было сказать к каким строкам/столбцам относится элемент